# Much of what he said I knew already

Tags: adverb-placement

[*Much of what he said I knew **already**.*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/already?q=already)

Is there a specific reason for *already* not to be placed in mid position *...I *already* knew*?

Comment: Only a prosodic reason: putting it last puts strong stress on it. This _could_ have an emotional content: such as irritation ("He should have known I would know it") or smugness ("I heard it before he did") or even scorn ("Why did he waste my time telling me?"). All of these could be present without putting  _already_ to the end, but doing so allows the speaker to put a particular tone of voice strongly on _already_.

Comment: "I already knew much of what he said" and "I knew much of what he said already" are also possible - not to add to your confusion!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's fine in either position.
Re: using a certain intonation to convey irritation or smugness, as mentioned in a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/283531/much-of-what-he-said-i-knew-already#comment529467_283531), that's possible in either position as well.